# How to do induction on the length of a list in Coq?

Tags: coq, induction

When reasoning on paper, I often use arguments by induction on the length of some list. I want to formalized these arguments in Coq, but there doesn't seem to be any built in way to do induction on the length of a list.

How should I perform such an induction?

More concretely, I am trying to prove [this theorem](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25386445/). On paper, I proved it by induction on the length of `w`. My goal is to formalize this proof in Coq.

Comment: For concreteness, is there any particular property of lists that you would like to prove?

Comment: @arthur-azevedo-de-amorim Thank you for replying. It is an automat as here: https://ibb.co/nNUXe5
I want to prove some theorems about it. The coq code can be seen here:
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25386445/

I failed to continue. 

I manage to prove it by induction on list length in paper using informal langauge. Just don't know how to use coq to prove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how to prove a general list-length induction principle.

```
Require Import List Omega.

Section list_length_ind.  
  Variable A : Type.
  Variable P : list A -> Prop.

  Hypothesis H : forall xs, (forall l, length l < length xs -> P l) -> P xs.

  Theorem list_length_ind : forall xs, P xs.
  Proof.
    assert (forall xs l : list A, length l <= length xs -> P l) as H_ind.
    { induction xs; intros l Hlen; apply H; intros l0 H0.
      - inversion Hlen. omega.
      - apply IHxs. simpl in Hlen. omega.
    }
    intros xs.
    apply H_ind with (xs := xs).
    omega.
  Qed.
End list_length_ind.
```

You can use it like this

```
Theorem foo : forall l : list nat, ...
Proof. 
    induction l using list_length_ind.
    ...
```

---

That said, your concrete example example does not necessarily need induction on the length. You just need a sufficiently general induction hypothesis.

```
Import ListNotations.

(* ... some definitions elided here ... *)    

Definition flip_state (s : state) :=
  match s with
  | A => B
  | B => A
  end.

Definition delta (s : state) (n : input) : state :=
  match n with
  | zero => s
  | one => flip_state s
  end.

(* ...some more definitions elided here ...*)

Theorem automata221: forall (w : list input),
    extend_delta A w = B <-> Nat.odd (one_num w) = true.
Proof.
  assert (forall w s, extend_delta s w = if Nat.odd (one_num w) then flip_state s else s).
  { induction w as [|i w]; intros s; simpl.
    - reflexivity.
    - rewrite IHw.
      destruct i; simpl.
      + reflexivity.
      + rewrite <- Nat.negb_even, Nat.odd_succ.
        destruct (Nat.even (one_num w)), s; reflexivity.
  }

  intros w.
  rewrite H; simpl.
  destruct (Nat.odd (one_num w)); intuition congruence.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 9):

There are many general patterns of induction like this one that can be covered
by the existing library on well founded induction.  In this case, you can prove
any property P by induction on length of lists by using `well_founded_induction`, `wf_inverse_image`, and `PeanoNat.Nat.lt_wf_0`, as in the following comand:

```
induction l using (well_founded_induction
                     (wf_inverse_image _ nat _ (@length _)
                        PeanoNat.Nat.lt_wf_0)).
```

if you are working with lists of type `T` and proving a goal `P l`, this generates an
hypothesis of the form

```
H : forall y : list T, length y < length l -> P y
```

This will apply to any other datatype (like trees for instance) as long as you can map that other datatype to `nat` using any *size* function from that datatype to `nat` instead of `length`.

Note that you need to add `Require Import Wellfounded.` at the head of your development for this to work.

Comment: Here is a slightly shorter variant `induction xs using (induction_ltof1 _ (@length _)); unfold ltof in *.`. But I'd prefer explicit naming: `induction xs as [xs IHxs] using (induction_ltof1 _ (@length _)); unfold ltof in IHxs.`

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the necessary imports are:

        Require Import Coq.Arith.Wf_nat.
        Require Import Coq.Wellfounded.Wellfounded.

Answer (score 4):

In case like this, it is often faster to generalize your lemma directly:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Section SO.

Variable T : Type.
Implicit Types (s : seq T) (P : seq T -> Prop).

Lemma test P s : P s.
Proof.
move: {2}(size _) (leqnn (size s)) => ss; elim: ss s => [|ss ihss] s hs.
```

Just introduce a fresh `nat` for the size of the list, and regular induction will work.