# How to do induction on the end of a list in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, coqide

In the standart way I have induction for list like this

- Approval is performed for `lst`
- Proving for `x::lst`

But I want:

- Approval is performed for `lst`
- Proving for `lst ++ x::nil`

For me, the place of `x` in the list is important.

I tried to write something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45872719/how-to-do-induction-on-the-length-of-a-list-in-coq/45876436), but not successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In such case, you need to prove your own induction principle. But here you're lucky because what you need is already in the standard library of Coq:

```
Require Import List.

Check rev_ind.
(*
rev_ind
     : forall (A : Type) (P : list A -> Prop),
       P nil ->
       (forall (x : A) (l : list A), P l -> P (l ++ x :: nil)) ->
       forall l : list A, P l
*)
```